# Netlogo - default value for turtle variable

Tags: default-value, netlogo

Can I define a default value for variables that turtles own

for example:

```
turtle-owns[variable1 (default-value true)]
```

Comment: Tyr is correct; no such language feature exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to define default values via the `turtle-owns` statement. Here is a workaround I use:
I create another procedure with all turtle-variables I want to define when a new turtle enters the world:

`to setup
   ...
   crt 1 [turtle.config]
   ...
 end`

`to turtle.config
   setxy ...
   set color ...
   set var1 ...
   set var2 ...
   ....
end`